# How to filter relations in extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I have defined some tables with relations.
`record`.`related_records` -> `related_record`

I already have a function to get records with filter conditions regarding relations to the main record.

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository;

class RecordRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    :
    public function getFilteredRecords($filter[]) {
      $recordQuery = $this->createQuery();
    
      $constraints = [];
      if ($filter['dateFrom']) {
        $tmpdate = new \DateTime($filter['dateFrom']);
        $constraints[] = $recordQuery->greaterThanOrEqual('begin_date', $tmpDate->format('Y-m-d'));
      }
    if ($filter['status']) {
        $constraints[] = $recordQuery->equals('related_records.status',$filter['status']);
    }
    
    $recordQuery->matching($recordQuery->logicalAnd($constrints));
    
    $rows = $recordQuery->execute();
    
    return $rows;
    }
    :
}
```

But in the result all relations are contained and I have to filter them again:

E.g.:
If I filter for all records which have a `relation_record` with `status = 'done'` I get only those `record`s which have at least one relation to a `related_record` with `status` equals `'done'`.
But for these records all relations are in the result (`related_record`s with `status` `'in work'`,`'planned'`, ...)

How can I restrict the result even on the related records?

Comment: IMO you're trying the wrong direction. If you wanna display all records based on a single relation_record, your base entity to start from should be a relation_record. `record.related_records`seems to be declared as an ObjectStorage, so of course, there are always all added relations part of the record model. The model and its data should not change by filters.

Comment: I can't change direction as the related records can't stay alone and if I get the (main/parent)  `record` this record again has all relations included.

Comment: So it's only a problem in your view. You wanna show only parts of your object. The repository gives you correct data: an object of your configured model - and that has *multiple* relations. As explained above, an object is independent of filters. Its properties never change by just getting the object.

Comment: Let me explain it all figuratively:  You go to the bookshelf and want cookbooks with lasagna recipes, but when you open them they *only* contain lasagna recipes and all other recipes should be gone.